# Updating dataframe fills columns with nan

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

In my `DataFrame`, I first replace values larger than a value with `nan`, then create another `DataFrame` with the same column name and fill it with random numbers. Then I update the original `DataFrame` with the newly created one, but in rows where I first set the value of the column `nan`, all other columns become `nan`. Original rows with `nan` in that column do not have the same problem. Here is what I mean in `pandas` syntax:

```
df[df['column_name'] > 40] = np.nan
column_series = df['column_name']
null_indices = column_series[column_series.isnull()].index
random_df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.normal(mu, sigma, size=len(null_indices)), index=null_indices, columns=['column_name'])
df.update(random_df)
```

Here are some numbers to explain the situation better:

Number of `nan`s in the column before replacing values `> 40` with `nan`: `6685022`

Number of rows with column value `> 40: 329066`

Number of rows with `nan` in every column except `column_name` after replacing: `329066`

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: I think I just did? One can create a DataFrame easily and apply the code to reproduce the problem.

Comment: If you post example data and exact expected output, you'll find you'll get better answers, faster. That way, it's easier for answers to verify correctness.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`df[df['column_name'] > 40] = np.nan` will fill the entire `df` with nulls, if the values in `column_name` are > 40.

Nihal is right, but i prefer this form (cleaner imo):

`df.column_name.loc[df.column_name > 40] = np.nan`

PS: it's a good idea to use Jupyter Notebook to see how the DataFrame looks like at each step.

Comment: That was stupid of me to forget about specifying the column, but I did not now the cleaner way. Thanks.

Comment: `df.column_name[df.column_name > 40]`. Not recommended. This is chained indexing and explicitly discouraged in the docs. Use `.loc` instead.

Answer (score 0):

use this recommended way:

```
df.loc[df['coulmn_name'] > 40, 'column_name'] = np.nan
```

Comment: Not recommended. Chained indexing is explicitly discouraged in the docs.

Answer (score 0):

may be this works

```
df.ix[df['column_name'] > 40,'column_name'] = np.nan # or indexof columns
column_series = df['column_name']
null_indices = column_series[column_series.isnull()].index
random_df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.normal(mu, sigma, size=len(null_indices)), 
index=null_indices, columns=['column_name'])
df.update(random_df)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem arises just with your first statement

```
df[df['column_name'] > 40] = np.nan
```

which means "replace ALL values in selected rows with `nan`". So the command

```
df.update(random_df)
```

inherits it.